# verbose_name_plural Naming convention

Tags: django

Should `verbose_name_plural` be `'ItemsForSale'`, `'itemsforsale'` or
`'items_for_sale'`?

I've googled, read docs.

```
class ItemForSale
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short**: it does not matter much since this has no effects on the coding side of the program. It is used to communicate with the user. Here probably the best option is `'items for sale'`.

The [**`verbose_name_plural`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural) is a *human readable* name you give to the objects.

So it makes sense to define this as:

```
class ItemForSale(models.Model):
    # ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'item for sale'
        verbose_name_plural = 'items for sale'
```

You can use this in forms, dialogs, and other means to communicate with the user. There are no naming conventions (like PEP-8 for example), since this deals with communication between the app and the user.

Its twin [**`verbose_name`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.verbose_name) for example specifies that:

> **`Options.verbose_name`**
>
> A **human-readable name** for the object, singular:
>
> ```
> verbose_name = "pizza"
> ```
>
> If this isn't given, Django will use a **munged version** of the class
>   name: `CamelCase` becomes `camel case`.

Comment: but what is the algorithm for "munging", for singular and plural forms?

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at Django Admin to check how the words will be shown.
Another example could be:

```
class Property(models.Model):
  ...
  class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'property'
    verbose_name_plural = 'properties'
```